# Как в Go Lang прочитать версию файла?

Tags: файлы, golang, файловая-система, метаданные

Как прочитать версию файла .exe в windows с помощью GO?
Стандартная FileInfo не дает этой информации(

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)
func main() {

    f, err := os.Open("C:/Program Files (x86)/file.exe")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("File name: %v\n", fi.Name())
    fmt.Printf("Is Directory: %t\n", fi.IsDir())
    fmt.Printf("Size: %d\n", fi.Size())
    fmt.Printf("Mode: %v\n", fi.Mode())
    fmt.Printf("Sys: %v\n", fi.Sys())
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

надо использовать Win32 API либу, например, [gonutz/w32](https://github.com/gonutz/w32)

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gonutz/w32"
)

func main() {
    const path = `C:/Program Files (x86)/file.exe`

    size := w32.GetFileVersionInfoSize(path)
    if size <= 0 {
        panic("GetFileVersionInfoSize failed")
    }

    info := make([]byte, size)
    ok := w32.GetFileVersionInfo(path, info)
    if !ok {
        panic("GetFileVersionInfo failed")
    }

    fixed, ok := w32.VerQueryValueRoot(info)
    if !ok {
        panic("VerQueryValueRoot failed")
    }
    version := fixed.FileVersion()
    fmt.Printf(
        "file version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        version&0xFFFF000000000000>>48,
        version&0x0000FFFF00000000>>32,
        version&0x00000000FFFF0000>>16,
        version&0x000000000000FFFF>>0,
    )

    // see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464(v=vs.85).aspx
    translations, ok := w32.VerQueryValueTranslations(info)
    if !ok {
        panic("VerQueryValueTranslations failed")
    }
    if len(translations) == 0 {
        panic("no translation found")
    }
    fmt.Println("translations:", translations)

    t := translations[0]
    // w32.CompanyName simply translates to "CompanyName"
    company, ok := w32.VerQueryValueString(info, t, w32.CompanyName)
    if !ok {
        panic("cannot get company name")
    }
    fmt.Println("company:", company)
}
```